# How can I prevent malicious Vuex mutations?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

So I have a Vue SPA quiz app, with a Vuex store that stores the number of questions the user has got right/wrong and so on. I'm then sending this data from the store to my server, to ultimately save it in my database.

Is this safe? Can't a malicious user simply mutate the vuex store manually from their browser (for example change the data to say they've got 100 questions in a row correct) and then hit my backend to save this in my database?

How would I prevent something like this, and verify that the data is genuine (i.e the user did, in fact, answer x amount of questions correctly) before saving it in my database?

Comment: Never trust anything client-side. Send the actual answers the user selected, not the count, and count the number correct server-side.

Answer (score 0):

Just as any other client side, a user can change the values before they are sent to the server, You need to send the data as it is changed and let the server do the math. So it is not safe to store in `vuex` first before sending to the server.

Basically what I use vuex for, is to store data that has been pulled from the server, rather than storing data that I intend to push to the server.

Comment: sure, but can't the user still send fake data to my server? If I'm hitting my backend with the user credentials and the answer they chose, can't someone just hit that route themselves to say they chose the correct answer, and do that 20 times?

Comment: You can do server side validation, i.e you can check if a user had chosen an answer  before and prevent them from doing it again. You should never trust anything from the client side, that is why you should always validate your data in your server side before accepting it